How to change Background Color of mat-chip of Angular Material 18
I dont understand the new Material theming.
How to make the background green?
<mat-chip class="make-green">
  Hello World
</mat-chip>

I read API Docs, with no success.

Theme color of the chip. This API is supported in M2 themes only, it
has no effect in M3 themes.
For information on applying color variants in M3, see
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-component-color-variants.


Can you share us your custom material theme file pls

I dont have one

So, Material 19 was released last night and changes this a bit. The M3 theming approach is still a little restrictive, for example you can't use hues any more, but it seems more intuitive and there is better access to be able to style individual properties.
The approach of changing a variable value is frowned upon:

Now the approach is to use mat.chips-overrides
In styles.scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

html {
    color-scheme: light dark;
    @include mat.theme((
        color: (
            primary: mat.$violet-palette,
            tertiary: mat.$magenta-palette
        ),
        typography: Roboto
    ));
}

In the component where you are using a mat-chip-set (or in the styles.scss if you want this to apply across the whole application)
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

mat-chip-set {
    @include mat.chips-overrides((
        outline-color: orange,
        disabled-outline-color: red
    ));
}

The result is:

The Angular Material documentation has been updated to include the available overrides. See https://material.angular.io/components/chips/styling
Obviously you need to be running Angular 19 for this to work.

It is as simple as this:
<mat-chip style="--mdc-chip-elevated-container-color: lightgreen;">
  One fish
</mat-chip>


Can you tell where you found Documentation for this?

there is no documentation. I inspected browser devtools.

That's great, and you can use a theme hue or color role with:  --mdc-chip-elevated-container-color: #{mat.get-theme-color($theme, on-tertiary)};

I had similar issues with the mat-select mat-header and mat-snackbar components. What worked for me was to change the color through the theme.scss file which is in the source folder. For example in my case
.black-snackbar {
  --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: white;
  --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #303030;
  --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: #2e98a3;
}

.header-panel.mat-mdc-select-panel {
  background: #2e98a3;
}
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
  pointer-events: none;
}



Note: This was for Angular 15.


this is not the Material Theming approach they recommend. And this wont work on Angular 18 anyway.

Material theming (M3) is confusing. M3 deliberately makes use of auto-contrasting colours; you can only provide primary and tertiary colours in a theme and M3 fills in the rest. When you use mat-chip M3 will automatically use colour from the neutral palette, so you need to use the selectable version mat-chip-option.
In my application I have a MatChipListbox that contains a set of MatChipOption. The MatChipListbox has a specific CSS class applied (my-chip) which will roll down to any nested MatChipOption.
<mat-chip-listbox multiple class="my-chip">
  <mat-chip-option selected>Chip Selection 1</mat-chip-option>
  <mat-chip-option selected>Chip Selection 2</mat-chip-option>
  <mat-chip-option>Chip Selection 3</mat-chip-option>
</mat-chip-listbox>

In my styles.scss file I define and apply a theme using the .my-chip selector:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$theme: mat.define-theme((
    color: (
        theme-type: dark,
        primary: mat.$orange-palette,
        tertiary: mat.$cyan-palette
    )
));

.my-chip {
    @include mat.chips-color($theme, $color-variant: tertiary);
}

@include mat.core();

The result is that selected chips use the tertiary colour variant (in this case, cyan) when selected.

See the documentation for more detail: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-component-color-variants
The alternative approach is to call the color-variants-backwards-compatibility mixin. This will enable the use of a color attribute like in M2.
